# odd number of elements in anonymous hash

Tags: perl

I'm trying to understand this Perl code...

If there is one stream it works, if there are 2 or more streams it warns with odd number of elements in anonymous hash.  It seems to return an array in that case.  How do I add the array elements correctly to @streams?  It appears to add correctly for the HASH case in the if clause. Is the else clause bunk?

```
 my $x = $viewedProjectDataObj->{streams};

    if (ref($x) eq 'HASH') {
        push(@streams, $x->{id});
    } elsif (ref($x) eq 'ARRAY') {

        print "$x\n";
        print "@$x\n";
        my @array = @$x;
        foreach my $obj (@array) {
            print "in $obj\n";
            print Dumper( $obj);
            push(@streams,  ($obj->{id}) );
        }
    }

    print "streamcount " . @streams % 2;
    print Dumper(@streams);


    my $stream_defect_filter_spec = {
        'streamIdList' => @streams,
        'includeDefectInstances' => 'true',
        'includeHistory' => 'true',
    };

    my @streamDefects = $WS->get_stream_defects($defectProxy, \@cids,             $stream_defect_filter_spec);
    print Dumper(@streamDefects);
```

I'm adding the next lines...

```
if ($defectSummary->{owner} eq "Various") {
    foreach (@streamDefects) {
        if (exists($_->{owner})) {
            $defectSummary->{owner} = $_->{owner};
            last;
        }
    }
}

my $diref = $streamDefects[0]->{defectInstances};
if ($diref) {
    my $defectInstance;
    if (ref($diref) eq 'HASH') {
        $defectInstance = $diref;
    } elsif (ref($diref) eq 'ARRAY') {
        $defectInstance = @{$diref}[0];
    } else {
        die "Unable to handle $diref (".ref($diref).")";
    }
```

It now errors with

Web API returned error code S:Server: calling getStreamDefects: No stream found
for name null.
$VAR1 = -1;
me
Can't use string ("-1") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at xyz-handler.pl line 317.

some Dumper output

```
$VAR1 = {
      'streamIdList' => [
                          {
                            'name' => 'asdfasdfadsfasdfa'
                          },
                          {
                            'name' => 'cpp-62bad47d63cfb25e76b29a4801c61d8d'

                          }
                        ],
      'includeDefectInstances' => 'true',
      'includeHistory' => 'true'
    };
```

Answer (score 17):

The list assigned to a hash is a set of key/value pairs, which is why the number of elements must be even.

Because the `=>` operator is little more than a comma, and the `@streams` array is flattened in the list, this

```
my $stream_defect_filter_spec = {
  'streamIdList' => @streams,
  'includeDefectInstances' => 'true',
  'includeHistory' => 'true',
};
```

is equivalent to this

```
my $stream_defect_filter_spec = {
  'streamIdList' => $streams[0],
  $streams[1] => $streams[2],
  $streams[3] => $streams[4],
  ...
  'includeDefectInstances' => 'true',
  'includeHistory' => 'true',
};
```

so I hope you can see that you will get the warning if you have an *even* number of elements in the array.

To fix things you need the value of the hash element to be an array *reference*, which is a scalar and won't upset the scheme of things

```
my $stream_defect_filter_spec = {
  'streamIdList' => \@streams,
  'includeDefectInstances' => 'true',
  'includeHistory' => 'true',
};
```

that way you can access the array elements as

```
$stream_defect_filter_spec->{streamIdList}[0]
```

etc.

And by the way you can tidy up your code substantially by letting `map` do what it's good at:

```
if (ref $x eq 'HASH') {
  push @streams, $x->{id};
}
elsif (ref $x eq 'ARRAY') {
  push @streams, map $_->{id}, @$x;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The assignment in:

```
my $stream_defect_filter_spec = {
        'streamIdList' => @streams,    # <---- THIS ONE
        'includeDefectInstances' => 'true',
        'includeHistory' => 'true',
};
```

is not correct, you get hash keys from the 1 3 5th ...  array element.

You probably want assign a reference to array, not the array itself:

```
'streamIdList' => \@streams,
```

example for the unwanted (as in your code):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump;

my @z = qw(a b c x y z);
dd \@z;

my $q = {
    'aa' => @z,
};
dd $q;
```

unwanted result:

```
["a", "b", "c", "x", "y", "z"]
Odd number of elements in anonymous hash at a line 12.
{ aa => "a", b => "c", x => "y", z => undef }

                                      ^-here
```

Example of assign a reference

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump;

my @z = qw(a b c x y z);
dd \@z;

my $q = {
    'aa' => \@z,
};
dd $q;
```

produces:

```
["a", "b", "c", "x", "y", "z"]
{ aa => ["a", "b", "c", "x", "y", "z"] }
```

The difference is clearly visible.

Comment: pls review answer again.  still issue